# Binary Search Tree (Struct format)

Tags: binary-search-tree

I was studying BST from GeeksforGeeks, and I came across this:

```
struct node* newNode(int data)
{
  struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node->data = data;
  node->left = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;
  return(node);
}
```

What is this format of defining a structure? Can somebody explain this?
I have always seen the structure format as:

```
struct *Name of the structure*
{
  body of structure
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a definition of a structure, it is a function that will return a struct node*.